Film or tv series about subterranean travel
It has been over 15 years since I saw this on TV. The plot was about subterranean travel, where initially a two man crew goes down with a high tech drill ship. They end up missing which sets up the plot and the assembling of the main cast and their new bigger drilling ship. They venture down into the earth but get lost and finds a tribe of subterranean creatures. As they make their escape, one of the two man crew appears and gives them a piece of the map of the subterranean world.
I don't know if this was a TV series or movie, hence why I am having trouble finding it. Any help would be welcome and appreciated.
It had visual effects from the 90's or early 2000's

Sounds a bit like At The Earth's Core (1976)

Also possibly Journey To The Center Of The Earth (2008), which had nothing to do with any of the other movies with the same name.

I looked over them, but it was neither.

Might be wrong, but I remember seeing something similar produced by Disney (or at least distributed by Buena Vista) as part of some Disney centered TV segment mid 90's on German TV. Maybe that could work as some hint?

I am currently looking through buena vistas stuff, but haven't found anything yet. Maybe i should have said it was live action?

Of the many adaptations of the classic "explore the center of the earth" tale, the one that best covers your criteria is:
Journey to the Center of the Earth (1993) starring David Dundara, F. Murray Abraham. TV movie - the pilot to a series that was never launched. Rescue mission of a drilling vehicle to save another drilling vehicle. Has various underground creatures and an unresolved ending.
The next best match is:
The Core (2003) starring Aaron Eckhart, Hillary Swank. Features a similar rescue mission, but no underground creatures.
Note: The resources for finding "center of the earth movies" are muddled. There have been at least 3 failed attempts to launch a TV series on the subject. In 2008 there were 4 movies named "Journey to the Center of the Earth," of which one was also released in the UK as "Journey to Middle Earth."

Journey to Middle Earth? Did they find any hobbits?
